# Connect to other network to use git repo

Tags: networking, command-line, nautilus, git

I have used Gigolo to create a bookmark/mount for a drive that I named engineering.  How would I be able to access this using the command line?  When I click on anything under Computer I can find a path that I can use in the terminal.  However there is no path when I click on engineering.   I have the ip address 193.etc user name and passwords but do not know how to access the files in the engineer drive from the terminal.  If I am not using correct syntax, I am still new to the non windows world.

[image: My Nautilus]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drives do not exist in the file system by their label... you can access it in CLI like so

```
mount /dev/sdb /any/directory/you/want

cd /any/directory/you/want
```

that is assuming that the drive is in fact refered to as sdb and a directory called `/any/directory/you/want` already exists

some basic info on mounting

http://www.linuxnix.com/2013/09/what-is-a-mount-point-in-linuxunix.html

some google-ing would do you well

https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=linux+how+mount+points+work&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

as for how a specific software handles mounting, you should read their documentation, which would most likely be found on their website